# Android: Facebook Id for contact

Tags: android, facebook, contacts

I am developping an app for personal use in Android.

Is there any way I can get a unique Facebook ID for a contact in my phone, if I already linked the contact with its Facebook profile? I don't know how to query Facebook for a given contact...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion is work through the [native Facebook SDK tutorial for Android](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/) and you'll be able to do what you're looking for.

To be more specific even, you can then use the [Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) to query this type of information. Once familiar with this API you can use the [User](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) object to look up both public and private information about a given Facebook contact.

Hope that helps!